# FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory On Angular Project

Tags: angular, node-modules

I was running Angular project on Vs code by ng serve and it was working properly but later after restarting pc, now it is showing **FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory**. I have tried all the possible solution from stack overflow.
Check this [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBckS.png).

I have tried this command. But not solving the error.

`set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8096`

I have created new [system variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVrcx.png) also but not working.

Comment: Can you confirm that the the environment variable is created? Open the command prompt and run "set". Check if you see that variable in the list. Then try to run "ng s" in the same prompt.

Comment: "set" is working but when I run "ng s" it showing error `this command  is not available when  running the angular CLI outside a workspace` @heringer

Comment: You need to enter in your Angular application folder to run "ng s".